# UnitTesting Always Returns Bad Request even Tested Method is Working Fine

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, mstest, testcase

I want to perform a unit test on my following method:

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostUser(User obj)
    {
        try
        {
            bool error = false;
            string errorMessage = "";

            if (obj.FullName == "")
            {
                error = true;
                errorMessage += "Please do not leave name area empty. ";
            }

            //Several other if statements to check everything is filled as expected by the user

            if(!error)
            {
                db.Users.Add(obj);
                db.SaveChanges();

                var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, obj);
                response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Request.RequestUri + obj.ID.ToString());
                return response;
            }
            else
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, errorMessage);
            }                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex);
        }
    }
```

I know that method performs well as it inserts data to database without popping any error. So, I watch some videos and check other questions related with UnitTesting, but unfortunatelly cannot make test response equal to expected response. Below is my test case:

```
[TestClass]
public class ProcessControllerTests
{
    private readonly ProcessController _processController;

    public ProcessControllerTests()
    {
        _processController = new ProcessController
        {
            Request = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage(),
            Configuration = new System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration()
        };
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void PostUser()
    {
        User testUser = new User
        {
            ID = 10,
            FullName = "Test User",
            Email = "test@unit.com",
            UserName = "TestU",
            Password = "teus123456"
        };

        var testResponse = _processController.PostUser(testUser);

        Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.Created, testResponse.StatusCode);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure where I am making the mistake.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you doing a unit test or integration test? What is the status message and code of the response?

Comment: I'm doing a unit test. Here are the test results after I rull all tests: `Message: Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<Created>. Actual:<BadRequest>.`

Comment: Debug the unit test and check if there is any message in the testResponse object that could point you in the right direction.